# Jquery events not applying on masonry appended items

Tags: jquery, ajax, masonry

I am loading image posts like facebook with scroll pagination using masonry. Each post has like button, which on clicked will send an ajax request and update the like count. This ajax method is working only for the first page items loaded. The subsequent appended items are not sending ajax requests, instead they are sending http request and reloading the page and updating like count. I tried debugging javascript and found this:
The first items loaded initially had 3 click eventlisteners including a.like_button

but the ones appended do not have this a.like_button click event listener.

Looks like the items appended must be applied events after loading.
Anyone knows what the problem is?

Thank you

Comment: post the code or a jsfiddle so we can have a better look at what you mean

Comment: thanks for the reply , figured out, have to use "on" jquery method to Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future. I was using just simple click method and the appended items are not getting appended the event listeners.

Comment: haha great, well at least you sorted it out